# how to make binary to bit 8 in python

Tags: python, string, binary, bit, converters

i have variable contains with binary with type int ([101, 1101, 11001])
but i want to xor it with another variable, so i must change to string and add "0" so it has 8 number
example 101 it'll become 00000101

i was trying change int to str but it cannot works. here's my code:

```
def bit8(input):
    print(input)
    y = str(input)
    print(y)

    index = 0

    for index, a in enumerate(y):
        y[index] = a + "0"

    return y[index]
```

input will contains with array [101, 1101, 11001] and it will become ["00000101", "00001101", "00011001"]
the idea is i will split them and i will add "0" and save it again to new array

but i don't know how exactly to do it. please help me

Comment: Curious why you will add a single 0, or do you mean add enough 0's to pad to 8 bits?

Comment: i want to add enough 0 to 8 bits @Carl_M

Comment: Applying XOR to strings is not the same as applying XOR to binary. Looking at the tags, binary, bit, and converters I think you may need to look at the built-in function `int()` more closely and also the `bin()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try  [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

```
l =[101, 1101, 11001]

c = "{:08d}".format
print([c(item) for item in l])
```

output #

```
['00000101', '00001101', '00011001']
```

As a function

```
def bit8(input):
    c = "{:08d}".format
    ou=([c(item) for item in input])

    return ou
```

Driver code

```
print(bit8(l))
```

zfill also works

```
l =[101, 1101, 11001]


def bit8(input):
    ou2=[str(i).zfill(8) for i in input]
    return ou2
```

Driver code #

```
print(bit8(l))
```

output for zfill method #

```
['00000101', '00001101', '00011001']
```

Comment: oh yeah, it's work. how to know if the array type is string?

Comment: What array?..I think input is `list` & `output` alos list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `XOR` directly and convert your input instead:

```
a = [101, 1101, 11001]

def toBinary (s):
    return int(str(s), base=2)

def toStringInteger (s):
    return int(f'{s:08b}')

a_int = [toBinary(s) for s in a]
# a_int is now [5, 13, 25]

# XOR with 11111 (^ is the XOR operator)
xored_int = [e ^ 0b11111 for e in a_int]
xored = [toStringInteger(s) for s in xored_int]

# Printing the XOR value
print(f"{a} XOR 11111 is {xored}")
>>> [101, 1101, 11001] XOR 11111 is [11010, 10010, 110]
```